# Confusion on using RETURN inside functions on PYTHON

Tags: python, function, return

When I try to create a .py file with return in a function like provided below

```
def results(s1,s2):
    return s1+s2

results(3,4)
```

it does not show the result when i try to run the .py file in terminal, why is it like this

And also please elaborately explain me where and how to use the RETURN statement and its purpose

Answer (score 8):

It doesn't show the result because you're not showing it! You have to print explicitly:

```
print results(3, 4)
```

When you call the function from Python's interactive mode, it does display the return value, but that's a *convenience* for development.

Answer (score 1):

You're not printing the result. Use this:

```
def results(s1,s2):
    return s1+s2

print results(3,4)
```